# Medoo SQL database select rows matching a date range

Tags: mysql, sql, date, strtotime, medoo

Is it possible to include [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) date comparison parameters when using medoo to SELECT rows from a database?

I'm using [medoo](http://medoo.in/) to make database work nice & simple - it's great. However, I'm not sure if I can (but suspect I can) include a date range like parameter when getting rows from my database.

Instead of going through all rows in a foreach routine of what is a large database, I was hoping I could optimise my SELECT/WHERE calls. My loose example/idea is here, but I'm not sure what will work.

```
$thelogs = $database->select("system_logs", 
    array("date", "category", "description","class"),
    array("date" => .........strtotime('-7 day'))
);
```

...More information pertaining the way dates are being saved.
Date column is set to datetime in MySQL 
Example entry would be: 2014-12-21 05:31:22 
In php i'm just using date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

Comment: You verified this to work if not going through medoo, didn't you?

Comment: ? Had seen tickets on github related to the subject, but couldn't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this to work with the following:

```
    $log_date_range = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-7 days"));

                        $thelogs = $database->select("logs", array(
                        "date",
                        "category",
                        "description",
                        "class",
                        "ID"), array(
    "date[>]" => $log_date_range
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Medoo is supported datetime condition. You can use it like this:

```
$database->select("system_logs", array(
    "date",
    "category",
    "description",
    "class"
), array(
    "date" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-7 days"))
));
```

Comment: This isn't returning anything from my database. Should this return only rows with dates specifically 7 days difference - or all rows where the dates are > 7 days ?

Comment: @feelsickened Check your datetime format in database row. The `xxx` in `date('xxx')` should match the format while you inserting the datetime data into database.

Comment: Sorry, the above doesn't work. Have updated original question with more information about the datetime format if that helps clarify or reveal the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $database->select("system_logs", array(
    "date",
    "category",
    "description",
    "class"
), array(
    "date[>]" => strtotime("-7 days")
));
```

Comment: This solution appears to return all rows no matter the date. Have updated the original question with saved datetime format info for clarification.